# How to set up SauceLabs for TestNg Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, saucelabs

Can someone please help me to figure out how to set up saucelabs for testNg on Java?
I’ve tried different guides, and it’s always different variations of set up, here's one of the examples that didn't work for me

```
    @BeforeClass
    public void init() throws MalformedURLException {
        MutableCapabilities sauceOpts = new MutableCapabilities();
        sauceOpts.setCapability("username", "oauth-xxxxxx.yyyyyy-51awdfsa");
        sauceOpts.setCapability("accesskey", "xxxxx-32b1-4c4d-ac70-yyyyyyyyy");

        DesiredCapabilities options = new DesiredCapabilities();
        options.setCapability("sauce:options", "sauceOpts");
        options.setCapability("browserVersion", "latest");
        options.setCapability("platformName", "windows  10");
        options.setCapability("browserName","chrome");

        Webdriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub"), options);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import com.saucelabs.saucebindings.testng.SauceBaseTest;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    /**
     * Example Test for running with the TestNG Sauce Bindings library.
     */
    public class SauceBindingsTestngTest extends SauceBaseTest {
        @Test
        public void correctTitle() {
            getDriver().navigate().to("https://www.saucedemo.com");
            Assert.assertEquals("Swag Labs", getDriver().getTitle());
        }
    }
```

Chrome/Win10 is the default so no setup code is required. If you want to change the configuration, check the Sauce Bindings docs below.

[Source Code for example](https://github.com/saucelabs-training/demo-java/blob/main/selenium-testng-examples/src/test/java/com/saucedemo/selenium/testng/demo/SauceBindingsTestngTest.java)

We have [a Demo Java repo](https://github.com/saucelabs-training/demo-java/) with any example you want, just browse the table of contents

We use [Sauce Bindings](https://opensource.saucelabs.com/sauce_bindings/getting-started/) to make the code so simple

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me,

```
DesiredCapabilities DC = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
DC.setBrowserName("chrome");
DC.setPlatform(Platform.WIN10);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://oauth-jayanth_balakrishnan-ae.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub"), DC);   //http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```